# How can i achieve the following using JavaScript or jqueries

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the Question button to stick on the bottom of the screen and when the page is scrolled down for it to sit on the footer. Again i want the same for the form too to stick on the bottom of the screen when you clicked on the Question button and when scrolled down for it  to  sit on the footer.

```css
#myDiv{
 max-width: 300px;
 background-color: blue;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea{
 margin: 5px;
}
 
legend{
 background: url(chat.png) no-repeat 1px 12px;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: Open+Sans!important;
 width: 90%;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #75777B;
 padding: 15px 22px 10px 35px;
 font-size: 16px;
 margin: 15px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

 
.box1,
.box2,
.box3,
.boxinfo{
 margin-left: 15px;
 font-family: Open+sans !important;
 font-size: 16px;
}

#box1{
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-right: 15px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
 width: 175px;
}

#box2{
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-right: 15px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
 width: 175px;
}

#box3{
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-right: 15px;
 width: 175px;
}

#boxbuton{
 float: right;
 margin-right: 28px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
 width: 120px;
 height: 35px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: #8F9091;
 border: none;
}

#boxinfo{
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 175px;
 height: 25px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-left: 16px;
 margin-right: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}

.switchbuton{
 background-color: rgb(255,237,0);
 box-shadow:  0px -4px 3px rgb(17, 17, 17);
 border-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
 font-family: Open+Sans!important;
 font-size: 18px;
 border: none;
 width: 205px;
 height: 45px;
 color: #75777B;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: blue url('chat.png') no-repeat 15px 10px;
    text-indent: 35px;
}

.footer {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  border-top: 5px solid #eee;
}


.nav-justified {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <!-- The justified navigation menu is meant for single line per list item.
            Multiple lines will require custom code not provided by Bootstrap. -->
        <div class="masthead">
            <h3 class="text-muted">Project name</h3>
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <!-- Jumbotron -->
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Marketing stuff!</h1>
            <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#" role="button">Get started today</a></p>
        </div>

        <!-- Example row of columns -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h2>Safari bug warning!</h2>
                <p class="text-danger">As of v8.0, Safari exhibits a bug in which resizing your browser horizontally causes rendering errors in the justified nav that are cleared upon refreshing.</p>
                <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="myDiv">
                <button type="button" id="hide" class="close" data-dismiss="myDiv" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <legend>Question?</legend>
                <form action="https://chat.scb.gm/ccp/chat/form/100000" method="post" target="_blank" onsubmit="return window.confirm(&quot;You are submitting information to an external page.\nAre you sure?&quot;);">

                    <span class="box1">Theme</span>
                    <input type="text" name="extensionField_Title" id="box1">
                    <br>
                    <span class="box2">Name</span>
                    <input type="text" name="extensionField_Name" id="box2">
                    <br>
                    <span class="box3">Phone</span>
                    <input type="text" name="extensionField_PhoneNumber" id="box3">
                    <br>
                    <span class="boxinfo">About</span>
                    <select name="extensionField_ccxqueuetag" id="boxinfo">
                        <br>
                        <option value="Chat_Csq23"></option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Continue" id="boxbuton">
                    <input type="hidden" name="author" value="Customer">
                    <br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="ccx chat">
                    <br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="extensionField_h_widgetName123456" value="Premium">
                    <br>

                    <input type="hidden" name="extensionField_chatLogo" value="">
                    <br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="extensionField_chatWaiting" value="Welcome. Please wait while we connect you to a customer care representative.">
                    <input type="hidden" name="extensionField_chatAgentJoinTimeOut" value="All customer care representatives are busy. Please wait or try again later.">
                    <input type="hidden" name="extensionField_chatError" value="Sorry, the chat service is currently not available. Please try again later.">
                </form>
            </div>
            <input id="info" type="button" onClick="this.style.visibility= 'hidden';" value="Question?" class="switchbuton">
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var button = document.getElementById("info");
                var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

                function show() {
                    myDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
                }

                function hide() {
                    myDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
                }

                function toggle() {
                    if (myDiv.style.visibility === "hidden") {
                        show();
                    } else {
                        hide();
                    }
                }
                $("#hide").click(function() {
                    myDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
                    button.style.visibility = "visible";
                });

                hide();

                button.addEventListener("click", toggle, false);
            });
        </script>

        <!-- Site footer -->
        <footer class="footer">
            <p>&copy; Company 2014</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you show only the relevant part of your code? It is hard to go through all of it not knowing what to look for.

Comment: The Question button and the form when you clicked on the question button

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = document.getElementById("info").offsetTop;
anchorButton=function(){
  if(window.scrollY < (x - window.innerHeight)){
     document.getElementById("info").className = "switchbutton infoStuck";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("info").className = "switchbutton";
  }
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', anchorButton, false);

var y = document.getElementById("myFormDiv").offsetTop;
anchorForm=function(){
  console.log(y);
  if(window.scrollY < (y - window.innerHeight)){
     document.getElementById("myFormDiv").className = "myDiv infoStuck";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("myFormDiv").className = "myDiv";
  }
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', anchorForm, false);
```

```css
.myDiv{
 max-width: 300px;
 background-color: blue;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea{
 margin: 5px;
}
 
legend{
 background: url(chat.png) no-repeat 1px 12px;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: Open+Sans!important;
 width: 90%;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #75777B;
 padding: 15px 22px 10px 35px;
 font-size: 16px;
 margin: 15px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

 
.box1,
.box2,
.box3,
.boxinfo{
 margin-left: 15px;
 font-family: Open+sans !important;
 font-size: 16px;
}

#box1{
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-right: 15px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
 width: 175px;
}

#box2{
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-right: 15px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
 width: 175px;
}

#box3{
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-right: 15px;
 width: 175px;
}

#boxbuton{
 float: right;
 margin-right: 28px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
 width: 120px;
 height: 35px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: #8F9091;
 border: none;
}

#boxinfo{
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 175px;
 height: 25px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-left: 16px;
 margin-right: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}

.switchbuton{
 background-color: rgb(255,237,0);
 box-shadow:  0px -4px 3px rgb(17, 17, 17);
 border-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
 font-family: Open+Sans!important;
 font-size: 18px;
 border: none;
 width: 205px;
 height: 45px;
 color: #75777B;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: blue url('chat.png') no-repeat 15px 10px;
    text-indent: 35px;
}

.footer {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  border-top: 5px solid #eee;
}


.nav-justified {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.info{
  position:relative;
 }
.infoStuck{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <!-- The justified navigation menu is meant for single line per list item.
            Multiple lines will require custom code not provided by Bootstrap. -->
        <div class="masthead">
            <h3 class="text-muted">Project name</h3>
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <!-- Jumbotron -->
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Marketing stuff!</h1>
            <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#" role="button">Get started today</a></p>
        </div>

        <!-- Example row of columns -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h2>Safari bug warning!</h2>
                <p class="text-danger">As of v8.0, Safari exhibits a bug in which resizing your browser horizontally causes rendering errors in the justified nav that are cleared upon refreshing.</p>
                <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="myFormDiv" class="myDiv">
                <button type="button" id="hide" class="close" data-dismiss="myDiv" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <legend>Question?</legend>
                <form action="https://chat.scb.gm/ccp/chat/form/100000" method="post" target="_blank" onsubmit="return window.confirm(&quot;You are submitting information to an external page.\nAre you sure?&quot;);">

                    <span class="box1">Theme</span>
                    <input type="text" name="extensionField_Title" id="box1">
                    <br>
                    <span class="box2">Name</span>
                    <input type="text" name="extensionField_Name" id="box2">
                    <br>
                    <span class="box3">Phone</span>
                    <input type="text" name="extensionField_PhoneNumber" id="box3">
                    <br>
                    <span class="boxinfo">About</span>
                    <select name="extensionField_ccxqueuetag" id="boxinfo">
                        <br>
                        <option value="Chat_Csq23"></option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Continue" id="boxbuton">
                    <input type="hidden" name="author" value="Customer">
                    <br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="ccx chat">
                    <br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="extensionField_h_widgetName123456" value="Premium">
                    <br>

                    <input type="hidden" name="extensionField_chatLogo" value="">
                    <br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="extensionField_chatWaiting" value="Welcome. Please wait while we connect you to a customer care representative.">
                    <input type="hidden" name="extensionField_chatAgentJoinTimeOut" value="All customer care representatives are busy. Please wait or try again later.">
                    <input type="hidden" name="extensionField_chatError" value="Sorry, the chat service is currently not available. Please try again later.">
                </form>
            </div>
            <input id="info" type="button" onClick="this.style.visibility= 'hidden';" value="Question?" class="switchbuton">
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var button = document.getElementById("info");
                var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

                function show() {
                    myDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
                }

                function hide() {
                    myDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
                }

                function toggle() {
                    if (myDiv.style.visibility === "hidden") {
                        show();
                    } else {
                        hide();
                    }
                }
                $("#hide").click(function() {
                    myDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
                    button.style.visibility = "visible";
                });

                hide();

                button.addEventListener("click", toggle, false);
            });
        </script>

        <!-- Site footer -->
        <footer class="footer">
            <p>&copy; Company 2014</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. How about the form?  The form appears when you clicked on the Question button, i want the same for it too.

Comment: The method is the same.

Comment: OK, I updated the source to show you how the method is identical.

Comment: Thanks once again but am seeing that the button goes down first and jump up at some point. Cant it stick at the screen end without moving down?

Comment: Am a student bro and trying to fix an assignment :)

Comment: I charge 65 dollars an hour for tutoring. Good luck with your assignment!

Comment: Thx a lot main but could you help with my last question?

Comment: It's a new question and needs a new stackoverflow question. This answered your original question of how to stick things to the footer edge of the page. Cheers!